# How does error value get assigned in React's AJAX and API example?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

In [React Docs - AJAX and APIs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) there is an example where a JSON object is created with a key that has no value.

I believe I am missing some fundamental understanding of JavaScript objects. What value is given to the `error` key in the following snippet and how does this value get there?

```
(error) => {
    this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
    })
}
```

Later, when the state is rendered, the value of `error` is assumed to have some `message` property. I have run the example code and it clearly works, but I am stuck trying to explain to another person how it works exactly.

```
if(error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [object property shorthand](https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/) ,

basically if you have a variable with the same name as the key, you can do :

```
const key = "someValue";

const obj = { key };

// instead of
const obj = { key : key };
```

```js
const name = "John";
const age = 30;

const obj = {
  name,
  age
}

console.log(obj);
```

In the example you provided, `error` is an object having `message` inside it, something like :

```
const error = {
  message: "some message",
  // ... 
}
```